# How to see explicit field name when having an elasticsearch mapping error

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a following error message of elasticsearch mapping.

```
{
  'index': {
    '_index': 'product-staging-2-products',
    '_type': 'product',
    'status': 400,
    '_id': '776896',
    'error': {
      'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception',
      'reason': 'failed to parse',
      'caused_by': {
        'type': 'number_format_exception',
        'reason': 'empty String'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I understand this error happens because one of fields of my "product" object expect a number but receive an empty string. But is there any way to explicit log which field receive this empty string?

Comment: Can you try to add the following query string parameter `&error_trace=true` in your indexing query?

Comment: Thank you very much, that solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [enabling stack traces](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-error-options) by appending the `&error_trace=true`query string parameter in your indexing query and you might get more information about the field that is causing this error.

Comment: That's what I want. But when I use Python client, and I pass it as a "query_params":{'error_trace': True} , it's seem no effect. Could help me with this case?

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant Python code.

Comment: I already found the issue. I use a too older version of es where no such option. Thank you.